# Error while installing php 7.2 in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-17.04

I got this error when run below command

```
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

Reading state information... Done

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-common
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-common'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-common'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-cli'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-cli'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-fpm'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-fpm'
```

Comment: you can see this: [This commands helps me:](https://superuser.com/a/1360028/1000698)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to manually add the `ondrej PPA` to be able to install PHP7.2 on Ubuntu 17.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

Or, by compiling it from the source by cloning the git repository, checking out the version that you want, make & make install

For more informations about compiling PHP from the source check out [how to build/compile PHP](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/build_system/building_php.html) from the source.

Comment: what's response that you are getting? and are you sure that the `apt-get update` command does not produce any errors/warngings?

Comment: May be issue with the ubuntu version. I did that installation successfully on ubuntu 16.04 but now i'm trying it on 17.04.

Comment: what is the response of executing `sudo apt-get install php7.2` ?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'

Comment: what is the output of the following command : `grep -rn 'ondrej/php' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173479/discussion-between-rawathemant-and-hassan).

Comment: I followed same step but still not installed.getting same error.I am getting error while update apt-get update. error like unable to find expected entry stable/source/sources . I am using ubuntu 17.04 and trying to install php7.3. getting error as unable to find package 7.3

Comment: @hassan I followed that command but still not installed. ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-22:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-22:~$

Comment: @kuldeep are you sure that you had added the repository successfully ?

Comment: @hassan I'am using VM with vagrant and I encounter the same problem after successful repository add and update. 
Here is the error that I get :
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3'

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem. 
This page helped me resolve it.
https://tecadmin.net/install-php-debian-9-stretch/

specifically, running these commands prior to the php install

`sudo apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https`

`wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -`

`echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list`

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks!!

Comment: getting this on `apt-get update`

`W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed`

Comment: Worked for me in Docker with Ubuntu 16.04 image. Remember to remove sudo (inside Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

1. Completely remove ALL versions of PHP

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
   ```
2. Force update from unsigned repository:

   Add this option in your sources.list (located at /etc/apt/sources.list):

   ```
   deb [trusted=yes] https://deb.sury.org/ stretch main
   ```
3. Upgrade the current packages to the latest version:

   ```
   sudo apt update  

   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
4. Install the required packages first on your system:

   ```
   sudo apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https
   ```

   Then import packages signing key:

   ```
   wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

   After that configure PPA for the PHP packages on your system:

   ```
   echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
   ```
5. Lastly, use one of the below options to install PHP of your requirements:

   **For installing PHP 7.2**

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.2-cli
   ```

   **For installing PHP 7.1**

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.1-cli
   ```

Comment: Why purge all existing php before updating? This is just asking for trouble. Install the new version and simply switch to using that instead. Remove old PHP once you are comfortably on the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a newer php was installed (7.4), so i just replaced the command with the 7.4 versions

```
sudo apt install php7.4 php7.4-common php7.4-cli php7.4-fpm
```

to know the version of php installed, use:

```
php --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you getting error like `php7.2`  `php7.2-curl` doesn't have installable candidate or not locate any package or dependencies is `php7.2-common` Or `libcurl3` Do this . Remeber Change your package name as per your requirements

You have to tackle in mature way. Install aptitude these ubuntu package manager will finds all dependencies, and will install one by one.

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

Now you have to check if aptitude can download it or not if download it follow instructions

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-curl
```

If you have gotten any error like this

```html
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-curl'
```

Any type on error i'm not talking about proper these errors

Try to add php package again

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update
```

Now try this command

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-curl
```

Aptitude will ask you you want to keep current version of all dependencies

```html
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     php7.2-curl [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Type `n` then `Enter`

Aptitude will find all dependencies and ask you to install all package type

```
y
```

Again

```
y
```

Then

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

For centos of rhel

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

It will Not enabling PHP 7.2 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in Apache2 do

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif

a2enconf php7.2-fpm
```

This method is not only for this error you can find any of php apache2 or ubuntu system package solution using aptitude.

```
Upvote if you find your solution
```